# AddThis and ShareThis conflict with Facebook Connect SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, addthis, sharethis

My iOS app uses the latest version of Facebook Connect as one method of allowing users to login.

I recently experienced a problem while adding an SDK that allows me to share posts via social networks, as well as obtain data for analytics on users' sharing activity within the app.

When I added the SDK for ShareThis, I received a compiler error that indicated a conflict between the ShareThis Facebook library and my official Facebook Connect SDK. So, I uninstalled ShareThis and added the SDK for AddThis. This also created a similar conflict.

Is there an easy way to segregate these libraries so the AddThis or ShareThis SDK don't conflict with Facebook Connect? Or, an easy way to point the Facebook authentication in AddThis or ShareThis to the Facebook Connect library that I've installed?

Comment: Having the same problem. Have you find a solution?

Comment: i have the same problem but when i login with facebook sdk and share using AddThis the session changes .... have you find an alternatives ?..